# Printing recursion in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have numbers in my Prolog database like this:

```
number(1).
number(2).
number(3).
number(4).
```

I want to create a recursive rule or any rule if it doesn't need to be recursive. I want to be able to enter a number into this rule and all the numbers should print until that number.

For example if I say `print_until(3)`. 
It should print out 1, 2, 3

Comment: Have you made any attempt at coding this? By the way, you need to choose a different name to `number` since that's a predefined predicate in SWI Prolog.

Comment: No, sorry should have mentioned I'm a complete beginner to prolog!

Comment: Is this a homework problem? And hint: you don't need (or want) a recursion in this case.

Comment: Its for my work so yes, but the actually problem is bigger so I simplified it because this is the bit I'm stuck on. Ok how would you suggest to do it...

Comment: If what you really want to do is iterate from 1 to N, you should look at SWI Prolog's `between/3` predicate (http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=between/3)

Comment: Yep but I'm actually working with dates so its harder as I'm having to use parse time, thats why I simplified the problem. Thats why I thought I had to use recursion

Comment: If your problem statement is taken literally, then your real data is expressed as facts in sort order of the data. Is that really the case? And do you care whether the output is sorted in some way? All of that matters. You may need to be more specific in your problem statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a raw version, so you have to care on formating, but it is a little help how loops could work:

```
 numbers(1).
 numbers(2).
 numbers(3).
 numbers(4).

 printuntil(X):-
      printhelper(1,X).

 printhelper(Z1,Y):-
      Z1=<Y,
      numbers(Z1),
      write(Z1),
      Z2 is Z1+1,
      printhelper(Z2,Y).
```

Comment: Thank you, this will defineley help me go in the right direction!

Comment: @user3078649 recursion could be helpful if you go backwards 3,2,1 ;)

Comment: how do we print from the knowledge database?? you use number/1 instead of what is in the database numbers/1. Maybe I'm mistaken but the OP wanted to print numbers from his knowledge base.

Comment: @ssBarBee: do you think a prolog newbie wants to print number/1(s) ?

Comment: I assume `number(Z1)` is a typo and really should be `numbers(Z1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
numbers(1).
numbers(2).
numbers(3).
numbers(4).

print_until(N) :-
    numbers(X),
    X =< N,
    write(X), write(' '), false.
print_until(_).  % adding this clause causes `print_until` to ultimately succeed
                 % after displaying the numbers.
```

I'm not sure how this maps to your actual problem. :)

Comment: love the idea with false at the end:) making prolog look for another number:)

Comment: ooo, thank you I've used some stuff from your code as well really helpful!